# Tutorial - Adding OpenCV JS to an ELECTRON project

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv, electron

**I've been stuck on this for the last few hours so I'll just post the answer to my question here so you won't have to.**

I'm running windows 10 and am developing an Electron application running Node v12.16.1 and electron v8.2.0.

I've been following various tutorials and none of them worked or managed to break in some other convoluted way. I tried opencv4nodejs and various other solution and this ended up the most reliable way to get OpenCV js to work.

**This is the way I managed to get it to work:**

```
<script async src="https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js" onload="onOpenCvReady()" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

just add this line at the end of your HTML file. This script will automatically load a pre-compiled js file from the OpenCV site which I'm pretty sure they never mention. This script is pretty much equivalent to `let cv = require('cv')` or similar things I've seen come by. Once this file is loaded it will call `onOpenCvReady()`.

In your HTML file, you can now just run the example from the OpenCV website.

```
<script>
let imgElement = document.getElementById('imageSrc');
let inputElement = document.getElementById('fileInput');

inputElement.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  imgElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
}, false);

imgElement.onload = function() {
  let mat = cv.imread(imgElement);
  cv.imshow('canvasOutput', mat);
  mat.delete();
};

// Entry Point: 
function onOpenCvReady() {
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'OpenCV.js is ready.';
}
</script>
```

I hope this works for you!

My total example roughly looked like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mainWindow.css">
<head>
    <title>Man Machine Exhibition</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <div class='container'>
    <p id="status">OpenCV.js is loading...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inputoutput">
            <img id="imageSrc" alt="No Image" />
            <div class="caption">imageSrc <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="file" /></div>
          </div>
          <div class="inputoutput">
            <canvas id="canvasOutput" ></canvas>
            <div class="caption">canvasOutput</div>
          </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
let imgElement = document.getElementById('imageSrc');
let inputElement = document.getElementById('fileInput');
inputElement.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  imgElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
}, false);
imgElement.onload = function() {
  let mat = cv.imread(imgElement);
  cv.imshow('canvasOutput', mat);
  mat.delete();
};
function onOpenCvReady() {
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'OpenCV.js is ready.';
}
</script>
<script async src="https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js" onload="onOpenCvReady()" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please only post questions in the question box - answers should be posted in the answer box, separately

Answer (score 0):

[image: OpenCV-FLow]

Opencv-flow is a Web and Electron Project and this project is opensource too.

I think you could check out how this page works and get some ideas from there.

Links:
https://opencvflow.org/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33336620)

Comment: They are using opencv-ts package and that has just few classes availible. F.e. essential for me is CascadeClassifier (for face detection purpose) and unfortunately, it's not supported yet. 
I wanted to experiment with YuNet and ofc that is also not there (but that's just few months old, so it didn't surprise me)